# How to dynamically generate and capture user input from modalDialog within a module?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

**Background**: I am creating a Donor/Sample registration application. The workflow is as such:

1. Users select which Vendor the Donors/Samples are from.
2. Users upload a file (using [`datamods::import_file_server()`](https://dreamrs.github.io/datamods/#import)).
3. Run some validation against that file (ie. `x` number of rows, `y` number of columns, etc., using `datamods::validation_server()`)
4. Select pre-existing or Create a new Field Mapping.

   4a) a Field Mapping is a mechanism for users to map the uploaded
   file columns to our database table columns.

   4b) If Create New, a `modalDialog` window should pop up, showing a 2
   column datatable, one column for File column names, one column of
   `selectInput()`'s  that are populated with our database table fields
   (columns).

I have this set up in such a way that a `registration_module` handles 1-3, and then within that, I have a  nested `fieldmapping_module` which takes as input:

1. the (validated) file data
2. the vendor selection
3. and the database columns

**Problem**: I cannot seem to make the dynamically generated `selectInput()`'s "visible" to Shiny.  Below is the `fieldmapping_module` code.

```
### FieldMapping module ####

fieldmappingUI <- function(id) {
  
  tagList(
    div(
      column(8,
             selectInput(
               inputId = NS(id, "fieldmapping_selection"),
               label = "Select Field Mapping",
               choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3") 
             ),
      ),
      column(4,
             shinyWidgets::actionBttn(
               inputId = NS(id, "create_new_fieldmapping_btn"),
               label = "Create New",
               icon = icon("file-alt"),
               size = "sm"
             )
      ),
      style = "display:inline-block",
      class = "form-group shiny-input-container")
  )
}


fieldmappingServer <- function(id, file_data, vendor_selection, db_cols) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(file_data))
  stopifnot(is.reactive(vendor_selection))
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- session$ns
  
    #observe for creation of new FieldMappings
    observeEvent(input$create_new_fieldmapping_btn, {
      
      fieldmapping_table <- data.frame(
        "File Columns" = colnames(file_data()),
        "DB Field Mapping" = rep("", ncol(file_data()))
      )
      
      #browser()
      
      for(i in seq_len(nrow(fieldmapping_table))) {
        fieldmapping_table[i,"DB.Field.Mapping"] <- as.character(selectInput(
          inputId = glue::glue("fieldmap_select_{fieldmapping_table$File.Column[i]}"),
          label = NULL,
          choices = db_cols
        ))
      }
      #browser()

      #display the table
      showModal(modalDialog(
        
        renderDataTable({
          DT::datatable(fieldmapping_table,
                        escape = 2,
                        selection = "none",
                        filter = 'none',
                        options = list(
                          dom = 't' 
                          ),
                        callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                                                       var $this = $(this.node());
                                                       $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                                                       $this.addClass('shiny-input-slider-input');
                                                         });
                                                       Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                                                       Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
          )

            
          }),
        title = "New Field Mapping",
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton(ns("submit_fieldmapping"), label = "Submit", icon = icon("paper-plane")),
          modalButton(label = "Close", icon = icon("window-close"))
          )
      ))
      
    })
   
    observeEvent(input$submit_fieldmapping, {
      browser()
    })
    

  })
  
}
```

**Excepted behavior**:  For example, say I have uploaded a file with 3 columns: `Subject_ID`, `Col_A`, and `Col_B`, and it has passed validation (done in the `registration_module`, not shown).

When I hit the submit button of the `modalDialog`, and the app is paused due to the `browser()` call, I am excepting to have access to `input$fieldmap_select_[column name]`(ex: `input$fieldmap_select_Subject_ID`), but I don't. I thought the  custom JS callback would achieve this, as it seems to have worked [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-dynamic-ui-in-data-table-output/99875/2?u=kyleweise) (and other code/apps I've come across while Googling).

On the `browser()` pause, if I enter `input` into the console to see the list of inputs, I indeed do see the dynamically generated inputs I created (the first three), but they are all `NULL`, despite having "set" them in the modalDialog window.
[image]

I am not too well versed in Javascript/Shiny interaction, but would appreciate any help I could get with this!  What am I doing wrong?

(cross-posted on [RStudio community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-dynamically-generate-and-capture-user-input-from-modaldialog-within-a-module/117902))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to include the server-side `ns` function in the dynamic generation of the input fields. ie:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(fieldmapping_table))) {
        fieldmapping_table[i,"DB.Field.Mapping"] <- as.character(selectInput(
          inputId = ns(glue::glue("fieldmap_select_{fieldmapping_table$File.Column[i]}")),
          label = NULL,
          choices = db_cols
        ))
      }
```

notice the `ns()` call around the `inputId`.